# Current reading, how does it work?

Tags: arduino, current, dc-motor

For a project I'm using an Arduino to drive a motor using a special pcb. In this board there is also a way to read the current drawn by the motor. Although I have the schematic I'm not 100% how this works and what the mechanism behind this is.

see the relevant part of the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Can someone quickly explain how I can use the Imotor2 connection to read the current, and why this works (the physics behind).

Thanks

R.

Comment: Simple Ohm's Law.

Comment: The motor current flows through R7, and you measure the voltage developed across R7 by that current.

Comment: The gate current of a MOSFET is close enough to zero in comparison to the motor current (when it is running) so you can assume the current through R7 is identical (for practical purposes) to the motor current.

Comment: A reverse diode across the motor will usually make things work better in general. It may have some issues but usually solves motethan it makes.

Comment: Thanks, I already assumed it's was ohm's law, but was confused by R24 and C3. :)

Answer (score 3):

R7 is the current sense resistor and it has a value of \$0.5 \Omega\$.  By measuring the voltage across R7, you can use Ohm's law to determine the current through the resistor.  The reason it has such a low value is so you have as small of a voltage drop as possible.  This allows most of the voltage drop to be across the motor.  R24 and C3 are there to act as a low pass filter to help smooth your current signal out.

Answer (score 2):

The motor current flows through R7, so by measuring the voltage across R7, the motor current is inferred from Ohm's Law.

$$
I(motor) = I(R7) = V(R7-ground) / R7
$$

R7 is 0.5Ohms or 50mV per Amp of motor current.

*edit*
The series resistor R24 and its associated capacitor form a lowpass filter to remove the motor drive PWM signal before driving the ADC input.

Comment: R24 isn't ignored. It, and C3, form a low pass filter to remove the PWM waveform that is used to control the motor.